# Theme causing SSL CA cert error

Tags: wordpress, ssl, plugins

Been troubleshooting an issue with Hostgator and it appears something in my custom theme is causing the following error when trying to download or upgrade plugins in Wordpress:

Download failed. Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Any suggestion on what I should be looking for to resolve this issue. If I switch to a default Wordpress theme - I'm able to download and update plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem - located in the functions.php file

this coding was causing the problem - figured I would leave this here in case others experience a similar issue.

add_action('admin_init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');